# How can I position flex items properly?

Tags: html, css

So I have a container inside of which there are a few flex items: an image, header, p and inline-block. THe problem is, I want to position an image on left, while header and p should be on the right side of image, and inline-block should be on the right corner.
Example is shown below:

[image]

But my container goes like this:

[image]

So my p goes under image, and inline-block is positioned properly, but for some reason it gets cut off from the right.

```css
.preview {
  /* flexbox */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #232323;
}

.preview img {
  /* image styling */
  float: left;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.preview h5 {
  /* header styling */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.preview p {
  /* p styling */
  color: #a1a5a5;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.score {
  /* inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #20d8da;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
  <img src="img/god_of_war.jpg" id="1">
  <h5>Assemble Your Squad and <br>Join the Battle</h5>
  <div class="score">8.3/10</div>
  <p>Nintendo Wii, PS4, XBox 360</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code like below.

```css
.preview {
  /* flexbox */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #232323;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.preview img {
  /* image styling */
  float: left;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.preview h5 {
  /* header styling */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.preview p {
  /* p styling */
  color: #a1a5a5;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  left: 130px;
position: relative;
}

.score {
  /* inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #20d8da;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  align-self: baseline;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks! it worked good with inline-block, but p still goes outside of image area, how could i display it on the right side of the image, like h5?